# Selecting SQL data based on multiple separate tables

Tags: sql

I'm doing some SQL practice and have been stumped by the following question.

I'm given the database schema:

```
Course (Course#, title, dept)
Student (Student#, name, program)
Enrolled (Student#, Course#, grade)
```

I'm trying the translate the following statement to SQL:

> List the names of all students who takes Computer courses or Science courses.

Initially I thought the answer might be something like this:

```
SELECT Sname 
FROM Course,Student,Enrolled
WHERE Course.dept = "Computer" OR Course.dept = "Science"
```

However, I feel like the rows in the table are not joined quite how I imagined, and that there is something off with this. How far off am I?

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g "Course#"), use single quotes for string literals (e.g. 'Science'), at least in ANSI SQL. (Tag dbms product used...)

Answer (score 2):

This is not that simple: first, you need to *join* the tables, and then you need to group by name to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM Student s
JOIN Enrolled e ON s.Student#=e.Student#
JOIN Course c ON e.Course#=c.Course#
WHERE c.dept = 'Computer' OR c.dept = 'Science'
GROUP BY s.name
```

`GROUP BY` is necessary because the same student may be taking both `"Computer"` and `"Science"` courses, in which case `JOIN` would produce multiple records for the same student. In this case you have an option of replacing it with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Okay, so when joining tables I need an attribute to Join around?

Comment: @dgbarrett Generally you do. There are cases when you want to produce a Cartesian product of two tables, and filter it later, but such cases are rare.

Comment: Cool, say I wanted to check if a student took both types of courses. Would I replace the OR with AND, or do I need to query again because a row would never have 2 departments?

Comment: I suggest do SELECT DISTINCT when you just want a distinct result. GROUP BY is mainly to be used when set functions are involved.

Comment: @dgbarrett No, replacing the `OR` with an `AND` would return nothing, because one string cannot be equal to two *different* strings at the same time. Assuming that names are unique, you would have to add `HAVING COUNT(*)=2` to get only students who have registered for both courses.

Comment: Also, double quotes are for identifiers (e.g "Course#"), use single quotes for string literals (e.g. 'Science').

Comment: I just want to test whether or not a student takes Computer and Science courses, can I just change the OR to AND?

Comment: @jarlh `DISTINCT`'s applicability is rather limited - in fact, the very first change request that OP wanted to implement (see his comment above) would require changing from `DISTINCT` to `GROUP BY`. I wasn't sure about doubleqotes vs. square brackets vs. backticks because OP did not specify a tag for his specific RDBMS vendor.

Comment: @dgbarrett No, you cannot. `c.dept = 'Computer' OR c.dept = 'Science'` is *always* false, for the same reason that `(x=1 and x=2)` is always false. See my comment above about adding the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 courses Computing (1) and Science (2) with the IDs 1 and 2, you need to do a query like this:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name FROM students s JOIN enrolled e ON e.student_id = s.id WHERE e.course_id IN(1, 2)
```

Sorry may have misread, if you need to do it by course type and the courses are tagged as dept = Computer, Science, Literacy etc... Do the following query:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name FROM students s JOIN enrolled e ON e.student_id = s.id JOIN courses c ON c.id = e.course_id WHERE c.dept IN('Computing', 'Science')
```

Or if you want to do an OR:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name FROM students s JOIN enrolled e ON e.student_id = s.id JOIN courses c ON c.id = e.course_id WHERE c.dept  = 'Computing' OR c.dept = 'Science'
```